# What is the most efficient way to split a combined factor column into two factor columns in an r data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, stringr

I have a large data.table (9 M lines) with two columns: fcombined and value
fcombined is a factor, but its actually the result of interacting two factors.
The question now is what is the most efficient way to split up the one factor column in two again?
I have already come up with a solution that works ok, but maybe there is more straight forward way that i have missed. The working example is:

```
library(stringr)
f1=1:20
f2=1:20
g=expand.grid(f1,f2)
combinedfactor=as.factor(paste(g$Var1,g$Var2,sep="_"))
largedata=1:10^6
DT=data.table(fcombined=combinedfactor,value=largedata)


splitfactorcol=function(res,colname,splitby="_",namesofnewcols){#the nr. of cols retained is length(namesofnewcols)
  helptable=data.table(.factid=seq_along(levels(res[[colname]])) ,str_split_fixed(levels(res[[colname]]),splitby,length(namesofnewcols)))
  setnames(helptable,colnames(helptable),c(".factid",namesofnewcols))
  setkey(helptable,.factid)
  res$.factid=unclass(res[[colname]])
  setkey(res,.factid)
  m=merge(res,helptable)
  m$.factid=NULL
  m
}
splitfactorcol(DT,"fcombined",splitby="_",c("f1","f2"))
```

Comment: your code returns error: `str_split_fixed function not found`

Comment: One straightforward way could be: `DT[, c("a1", "a2") := as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(fcombined), "_")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)]` (and then to convert `a1` and `a2` to `numeric` type). Not sure if it'll be faster though.

Comment: `str_split_fixed` is in library(stringr)

Comment: as far as I remember the strsplit is slower than str_split_fixed. Splitting on the levels instead of converting the entire column to character also reduces processor time.

Comment: `colsplit` in the `reshape2` package does this, but starting with just a vector (the column to split) and returning a `data.frame` which can be `cbind`-ed back to the original data. It does not operate within the `data.table` directly, so I don't know how efficient it would be. But worth considering/benchmarking.

Comment: The code you're using is pretty much what I would do, so I can't comment on efficiency improvements. Two minor things: DT and helptable are both data.tables, so m will be a data.table and you can delete by reference `m[,".factid":=NULL]`. Similarly, you can create res$.factid by reference: `res[".factid":=unclass(get(colname))]` or something like that. And with setnames, if you're renaming everything, you can just pass the new names: `setnames(helptable,new_names)`.

Comment: @JohannesKutsam, +1 on using levels. I'll write back if I manage to get something better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does the trick and is about 5x faster.

```
setkey(DT, fcombined)
DT[DT[, data.table(fcombined = levels(fcombined),
                   do.call(rbind, strsplit(levels(fcombined), "_")))]]
```

I split the levels and then simply merged that result back into the original `data.table`.

Btw, in my tests `strsplit` was about 2x faster (for this task) than the `stringr` function.

Comment: @eddi, I think it's nicer if you include benchmark results when you claim precise x-times faster. You're doing the tests anyways... It'll help others to include yours in their results directly when/if others answer as well.

Comment: @Arun haha, it probably would be nice :) I didn't include it here because of mainly laziness, but also because I don't think the precise benchmark matters too much in this case; also do note the use of the word "about" above, rather than precise numbers